# Perl string eq and or together alwas are true

Tags: string, perl

I'm parsing xml using `XML::Parser`; I have the tags "my_id" and "total" in my xml.
When I try to combine both with "or", it always evaluating the if as true:

```
if($elt eq "my_id" or "total")
{
               return 1;
               $context = $elt;
}
```

If I break it to:

```
 if($name eq "my_id")
    {
          print($name." ".$xml_tag_val."\n");
          return 1;
    }
    elsif($name eq "total")
    {
           print($name." ".$xml_tag_val."\n");
          return 1;

    }
```

It is working just fine.
What is wrong with the first if?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write your conditions like this:

```
if($elt eq "my_id" or $elt eq "total")
```

Answer (score 4):

The main problem here is that `or` does not work that way. This is a common misconception about how `or` works. You *can* use an expression in `eq`, but the expression you have uses `or`, which has lower [precedence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity) than `eq`, and therefore is not part of the string comparison. Also, an or-expression only ever returns one of its parameters, whichever is true. And with strings, everything except `0` or the empty string is true. This is the reason your statement always returns true: `"total"` is a true expression in Perl.

What you have written can be clarified with parentheses:

```
if( ( $elt eq "my_id") or "total")
#   ^----       -----^
```

Where you can clearly see that `or "total"` will make the expression always true. Note also that it would be wrong to do this:

```
if( $elt eq ( "my_id" or "total") )
```

Because the `or`:ed expression would always return `"my_id"` and never even check `"total"`.

What you need to do is to do the check once for each parameter:

```
if( ($elt eq "my_id") or ($elt eq "total") )
```

Or if you have a list of parameters, and `$elt` contains a non-false value (i.e. `0` or empty string, or `undef`), you can use `grep`:

```
if (grep { $elt eq $_ } @parameters)
```

Or more correctly, use the `any` function from `List::MoreUtils`:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(any);
if ( any { $elt eq $_ } @parameters )
```

Comment: There's always more than one way to do it.

Comment: Tim Toady Bicarbonate? Personally, I much prefer Tim Toady over the python mantra that says there's only one way to do it. That said, nowadays I use python a lot more than I use perl.

Answer (score 0):

That `eq` doesn't apply to the left hand side of the "or". The precedence of the `eq` is higher, so it tests that first.

That first expression is actually:

```
if ( $elt eq "my id"
          or "total" );
```

Because "total" is a string, it's therefore true. You're not testing it's equivalence at all.

You could rewrite as:

```
if ( $elt eq "my id"
  or $elt eq "total" ) {
  #.... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `$elt eq "my_id" or "total"`

As others have noted, this is not doing what you intend. With parentheses, this is equivalent to `($elt eq "my_id") or "total"`. The expression is always true because even if `$elt` is not string-equal to `"my_id"`, the second part of the expression, `"total"`, is a truthy expression.

The perl motto is "there is more than one way to do it." This certainly applies here; there are a number of ways to test whether `$elt` is string-equal to either `'my_id'` or `'total'`.

```
if (($elt eq 'my_id') || ($elt eq 'total')) ...
if ($elt eq 'my_id' || $elt eq 'total') ...
```

I prefer the first of the above. My personal operator preference rule: Use parentheses except for expressions such as `$a+$b*$c`. You don't need parentheses for `$a+$b*$c` because everyone knows that multiplication and division distribute over addition and subtraction. For anything else, use parentheses. But that's just my preference. There's more than one way to do it.

```
if ($elt =~ /^(?:my_id|total)$/) ...
```

That's a completely different way to do it. The parentheses are important here.

For yet another way to do it, use a post-if:

```
return print("$name $xml_tag_val\n") if $elt =~ /^(?:my_id|total)$/;
```

You don't need that `$name." ".$xml_tag_val."\n"` stuff. Learn the difference between `'$non_interpolated_string'` and `"$interpolated_string"`. Single quotes and double quotes are rather different beasts in perl.

Comment: `/^(?:my_id|total)$/` would probably be better, unless you want to capture a string.

Comment: @TLP: Fixed. 15_char_pad.